# Basement outlet on exterior wall oozing water

Tags: receptacle, waterproofing, brick, masonry

I walked downstairs and saw my outlet oozing a brown substance. Guessing it is dirty water from the outside (I have a sprinkler going and it is hitting this part of the house). Also guessing it is getting in through these cracks in the brick. What should I do about this?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: adjust sprinkler

Comment: @Ruskes should I adjust the rain too?

Comment: If this is a rain damage, then you have a serious problem.

Comment: Does water run down this wall when it rains? and where is this outlet, relative to the wall - above or below grade?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's time for a bit of re-pointing.

The house is basically no longer weather-tight. Although the sprinkler may be worse as it's spraying horizontally, rain will also get in there & wreak havoc over an extended period.
The outlet was your easy clue, the rest of the damage will be where you currently can't see it, in floorboards & joists [& house frame if that's just a stone veneer over a wooden structure.]

Answer (score 2):

First off, turn off the breaker for that outlet and pull out the outlet and access the extent of any damage /dampness to the outlet and wiring. Hopefully, the water is leaking through those cracks in the mortar so that would be your first fix. You can do it yourself or get a tuck pointer to remove the lose mortar and add new mortar I wouldn't use caulk or other sealants because they will fail in a few years and you'll be back to repairing it again. After fixing that, which needs to be done soon, observe that outlet for any leaking. If it still leaks, then it's probably a foundation crack, a more difficult repair job.

Comment: I have to politely disagree - it seems to me that a tube of SLAB or something similar ("concrete repair" caulk) would be a good idea until repointing can be done - any idiot can use a caulk gone, but finding someone who can repoint and do it well could take time.

Comment: @negacao  Polite disagreement accepted.  The problem is that most people would use the quick fix and then put off the real fix and then forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Forensic evidance shows:

This is wood rot.

The water passing true the mortar and bricks would not be so dark.

You will have to open it and assess the damage.